# does << (input redirection in append mode ) works only for newline?

Tags: command-line

while reading about file creation in linux I got :

> Another way to create a file at the terminal is `cat > <filename> << EOF`. A new file is created and you can type the required input. To exit, enter EOF at the beginning of a line.

so I tried this on my shell prompt

```
$ cat > test1.txt <<ABC
> This is just a test file.
> ABC
$ cat test1.txt
This is just a test file.
```

here when I typed `ABC`(it could be anything - just for matching pattern) .in the newline it worked(accepted as it would have done in case of `ctrl` + `C`),but when I tried

```
$ cat >> test1.txt <<ABC
> just for a trial
> though ABC
> it didnt worked.
> ABC
$ cat test1.txt
This is just a test file.
just for a trial
though ABC
it didnt worked.
$
```

doing this , it only worked in the newline. Does it mean that `<<` works for newline,

And what's going on inside `cat> test1.txt <<ABC` exactly ??

Comment: "<<" is *not* input redirect in append mode... it's called an ["here doc"](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) in bash.

Comment: Thanx @Rmano ,I didn't knew that ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final 'EOF' (the LimitString) should not have any whitespace or other characters in front of the word, because it means that the LimitString (in your case `ABC`) will not be recognized.<sup>**1**</sup>

<sup>**1**</sup><sub>Adapted and revised from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2954835/2907484</sub>

Comment: +1. More info on "here docs" here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2954835/2907484